# Filling NaN values via specific column and specific category

Tags: python, nan

I am coding in python and need some assistance. I have a dataframe and I want to fill each column with the average from each different category (pnns_group_1).
[image]

Currently I have the following code:
[image]

But my output is the average for the whole column, not the average per group:
[image]

So, to confirm I need the average from 'Cereals and potatoes' groups to be different from the average of 'Sugary snacks' groups. Thanks in advance for helping me with my problem.